# Having trouble making relative imports in sibling directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Im having trouble importing from sibling directories.

I would like to set up my package so that all of these aspects simultaneously work.

Here is my module setup:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    code/
        __init__.py
        model.py
        helper.py
    notebooks/
        __init__.py
        notebook1.ipynb
```

Imports in `model.py`:

```
from helper import *
```

When running from the command line in package/ I set PYTHONPATH=. and I can run model.py

Imports in `notebook1.ipynb`:

**First scenario**:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from code.model import MetaModel
```

Results in: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.model'; 'code' is not a package

**Second scenario**:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('../code')))
from model import MetaModel
```

This works. Why can I not use the first scenario.

Comment: Think you might be looking for `from ..code.model import MetaModel`

Comment: Resulted in ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package. I also started the jupyter server from inside `package/`

Comment: You either need to get rid of `sys.path.insert(...)` or adjust the relative import syntax for the changed path.